# Random Forest overfitting with `n_estimators=1`, `max_depth=1 and `max_features =1`

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, overfitting

I am trying to stop my RF from overfitting. I am using time series data with 1 day time lag, to predict the current price. I am using this function to shift my independent features back 1 day:

```py
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    #Ref: https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    col_names = data.columns
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [(f'{col_names[j]}_t-{i}') for j in range(n_vars)]
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg
```

I then fit my RF, I have attempted many different parameters however the model still overfits.

```py
n_lags = 1

lagged_X = series_to_supervised(df, n_in=n_lags, n_out=0, dropnan=True)
y = df[RESPONSE_VAR][n_lags:]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    lagged_X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42,
    shuffle=False)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1, max_depth=1, max_features=1)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

preds_train = rf.predict(X_train)
preds_test = rf.predict(X_test)
mae_train = mean_absolute_error(y_train, preds_train)
mae_test = mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds_test)

print(f'mae_train: {mae_train}')
print(f'mae_test: {mae_test}')

> mae_train: 683.4959502405592
> mae_test: 2491.3775235802696
```

My `lagged_X.shape` is `(3179, 220)`. I would have assumed constraining the model to only 1 tree and 1 feature, that the model would not be able to overfit? I have displayed the `rf.feature_importances_` and attempted to drop too informative columns (?) with higher amounts of estimators and less feature constraints however, this also did not work.

Can I get my Train and Test scores to converge?

Comment: I think it looks like overfitting but I'm not sure that it can really be called overfitting here: the model is too simple so the problem is not really that it learns too much detail, it just can't learn much. From this point of view it looks more like bias but I'm not sure either.